# PDFStreamEngine Engine Properties Issues Migrating to PDFBox 2.0.x

Tags: pdfbox

Our department has inherited code that uses Apache PDFBox 1.8.x or earlier and we are in the process of trying to migrate it to Apache PDFBox 2.0.x. I have versions of the last three major versions (1.7.x, 1.8.x, and 2.0.x) that I've looked to for guidance as well as the [Migration to PDFBox 2.0.0](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html) and the [PDFBox Jira Board](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX/).

We have a class that extends PDFStreamEngine and there used to be a constructor that took a `Properties` object and used that to populate the internal `operators` field. I don't see any comparable features to initialize this field and all output is dropped because there are no registered operators.

Is there a recommended way to set these operators or do I just need to borrow the old properties processing code from 1.8 and add it to my extended class?

Comment: See in the source of PDFGraphicsStreamEngine (or others) the addOperator calls. I suspect that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tilman. I did see that and in other classes like LegacyPDFStreamEngine and PreflightStreamEngine, but didn't know if I was missing something where it was driven by a properties file or other generic configuration. I'll roll my own. :-)

Comment: Ok, good luck... feel free to answer the question yourself, and/or submit a text to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3330 . I just don't have a good idea for a text.

Comment: I wound up adding the calls to addOperator in our constructor. I'm in the final stages of our refactoring and we were dropping all data silently because the operators weren't initialized. We're still dropping data, but a little less now. I think there is an operator (likely one of our custom ones) that isn't behaving correctly, but it's tough to identify where.

Comment: Be sure that addOperator isn't called twice for an operator. To check this, make this replacement in PDFStreamEngine: `public final void addOperator(OperatorProcessor op)
    {
        op.setContext(this);
        if (operators.containsKey(op.getName()))
        {
            LOG.warn("Operator name '" + op.getName() + "' for parameter " + 
                    op.getClass().getName() + " is already registered for " + 
                    operators.get(op.getName()).getClass().getName());
        }
        operators.put(op.getName(), op);
    }`

Comment: Thanks again Tilman. I added this to my local PDFBox code and it doesn't look like I have any dupes, but I did have a null. Still dropping text. I'm going to look to see if there was any undocumented changes we were using in the old code for any of the operators. Should this check be added to the code code?

On a different issue, do you think the patch that I submitted for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3576 has any chance of getting picked up?

Comment: The check is just something that I did for myself. Re your dropped text, you'll have to do some good old fashioned debugging of both versions. That's how I solved many regressions in the 2.0 version re text extraction differences. It took hours sometimes but the job was done. Btw PDFBox 2.0 sometimes swallows certain texts that 1.8 didn't (because these were just a guess), so don't forget to compare off-the-shelf text extraction. Re PDFBOX-3576 see my last comment.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote on the Jira task. Our engine is modeled after PDFTextStripper and it looks like the charactersByArticle field isn't being updated. In the old PDFBox code, I trace it through processSubStream() and at the end of processing the operators, charactersByArticle is populated. In the new processStreamOperators(), at the end of processing the same operators, charactersByArticle is created, but empty. I'm trying to isolate where that field is being (or not being) updated.

Comment: `charactersByArticle` is filled in processPage. That one is called by processPages(), which is called by writeText().

Comment: Yeah... I've drilled down a little further under the covers... OLD: writeText()->processPages()->processPage()->processStream()->processSubStream()... At the end of processSubStream(), charactersByArticle  is fully populated... NEW: writeText()->processPages()->processPage()->processChildStream()->processStream()->processStreamOperators()... At the end of processStreamOperators() charactersByArticle is created, but empty... Still digging :-)

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious... I can see where charactersByArticle gets checked and where it is initialized with a new ArrayList, and where there are gets done against it, but I don't see where it is set or updated... Confused... In the old code, it is created, but empty at the start of processSubStream(), but populated at the end of the same method. Some behind the scenes magic with the PDFStreamParser or the processOperator()?... Still digging

Comment: As I said, try to run an off the shelf PDFBox 2.0.4 text extraction. Either charactersByArticle  is filled, then the bug is in your fork. Or it isn't filled, then the best would be to send me the PDF file for analysis.